# How to read from file in c++ in ccs in linux ?

Tags: c++, linux, readfile, code-composer

I have got a problem, I want to write code which reads from file, i tried ifstream type but it doesn't work on my linux. Does anyone had similar problem ? I write this code in Code Composer Studio,on Code Blocks it works. i have an error that say "method 'fail' could not be resolved.) Down below my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
ifstream inFile ("input.txt"); 
if (inFile.fail()) 
{ 
    cout << "Could Not Open File\n"; 
 } 
else 
{ 
   cout << "File opened succesfully\n"; 
}  
}
```

Comment: Is there a 'input.txt' next to the executable? If not no wonder that it can not be opened.

Comment: Yes i have input.txt where it is suppouse to be

Comment: if you do ofstream outFile("output.txt"); does that work?

Comment: It fails during compilation or when you're running it?

Comment: When i build project this message appears. It is strange because when i run it in codebloks it works. When i type inFile. , the ccs tell me that there is only option fo basic_ifstream